# Method of characteristics of a system of first order pdes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of first order PDEs

$
\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} v_1 +  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} p_1 + \eta(x_1) v_1 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} v_2 +  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} p_2 + \eta(x_2) v_2 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p_1 +  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} v_1 + \eta(x_1) p_1 = f(t) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p_2 +  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} v_2 + \eta(x_2) p_2 = 0 
\end{eqnarray}
\right.
$

with initial condition $v_1 = v_2 = p_1 = p_2 = 0$ at $t=0$,
where $v_1,v_2,p_1,p_2 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $ are the unknown functions, $\eta, f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are given smooth functions.

I would like to consider this system of PDEs with the method of characteristics. I know the method for a single PDE, but I don't know how to find the characteristics of such a system.

Could anyone please give some advice?

Regards.

I could understand that this system is a hyperbolic one.

Take $U=(v_1,v_2,p_1,p_2)'$, then the system can be rewritten as

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} U 
+ \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~0 ~ & 0 ~ & 1 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
 1 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 
\end{array}
\right) 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} U
+  \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 1 \\
 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 1   & 0   & 0 
\end{array}
\right) 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} U
+ \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~\eta(x_1) ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & \eta(x_2)   & 0   & 0 \\
 0 ~ & 0 ~ & \eta(x_1) ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & \eta(x_2) 
\end{array}
\right) 
 U 
=\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
  0 \\
 0  \\
 f(t) \\
0 
\end{array}
\right) .
$

Take $B_1 = \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~0 ~ & 0 ~ & 1 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
 1 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 
\end{array}
\right) $, 
$B_2 = \left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 1 \\
 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 1   & 0   & 0 
\end{array}
\right) $, then define a matrix

$B (y_1,y_2)= y_1 B_1 + y_2 B_2 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 ~0 ~ & 0 ~ & y_1 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & y_2 \\
 y_1 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 ~ & 0 \\
 0   & y_2   & 0   & 0 
\end{array}
\right)$.

The eigenvalues of $B$ are $-y_1, y_1, -y_2, y_2$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are
$(-1, 0, 1, 0)', (1, 0, 1, 0)', (0, -1, 0, 1)', (0, 1, 0, 1)'$.

Since the eigenvalues of $B$ are distinct and all real and the four eigenvectors are linearly independent, the system of first order PDEs is hyperbolic.

Comment: This question has been answered on [http://mathoverflow.net/](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193330/method-of-characteristics-of-a-system-of-first-order-pdes). I would like to express my gratitude to Robert Bryant for giving the answer and explaining the method of characteristics, and to Igor Khavkine for discussing the method of characteristics.